# Connect to google search console API from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-search-console

I am trying to get data from google search console `https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites` but from Node backend not the front end, I have created OAuth 2.0 Client IDs and API key on the google api console. But I can find the way to connect.

I am following this guide https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/searchconsole/index.html

I just want to be able to make read requests from node.

I tried this

```
import { google } from 'googleapis'

const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
  YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
  YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);

google.options({ auth })

const searchconsole = google.webmasters({ version: 'v3', auth })

const sites = await searchconsole.sites.list({})
console.log(sites)
```

I get this error even thou all the credentials are correct

```
'Error: No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set.'
```

Comment: Try going though the sample for [Google drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) it will show you how the authorizaotn should work. Just change out the drive service for webmasters should work

Comment: The authorisation is not the problem, the problem is interacting with searchconsole to get the list of sites

Comment: You need to create a service first const service = google.webmasters({version: 'v3', auth});

Comment: Thanks, the service works, but I cannot find where is the documentation to interact with this `service` to get this `https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites`

Comment: Either check the source code or just look for methods with the same names as the documentation https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/parameters  there should be something like service.sites.list  the lirbary is generated from the discovery doc for the api so it should match up perfectly with the documentation.

Comment: Wow this is so cryptic why would they hide it in such a way. I cannot find anything that gives me the list with this method

Comment: They dont hide it really they just have a lot of APIs they cant document every lanauge.  what about this https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/main/samples/webmasters/query.js

Comment: How can I know how to access the list of sites if they do not document it?

Comment: It is documented. I linked you the documentation for [web master tools](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sites/list)   Then there is again the source code for that module in the client library  [webmasters v3](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/main/src/apis/webmasters/v3.ts)   What they dont do is hold your and and give you an example method in every api in every language doing everything anyone may want to do.

Comment: I found the way using `service.sites.list({})` but now I get
`Error: No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set.`

Comment: your authorization isnt working

Comment: But I followed the steps as in here https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/tasks/index.html#samples and all is correct

Comment: you didnt need to open a new question you should have stayed with this one.   Your code doesnt look anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

According to the comments, seems you already got the authorization pieces working, now, if you want to list the sites to get search analytics data for each owned site by the authorizing user, you can do something like the following code:

| Use Google Search Console API | [<kbd>Run in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-70861719) |
| --- | --- |

```js
const webmasters = googleClient.webmasters('v3');

// List the owned sites
const sites = await webmasters.sites.list({});
const sitesAnalytics = [];
  
for await (const site of sites.data.siteEntry) {
  const response = await webmasters.searchanalytics.query({
    siteUrl: site.siteUrl,
    requestBody: {
      startDate: '2021-01-01',
      endDate: new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0],
     },
   });

  sitesAnalytics.push({ site, analytics: response.data});
}

console.log = `Got a successful response from Google Search Console: ${JSON.stringify(sitesAnalytics)}`;
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben, but my problem is that the pop up window to authorise happens on my browser cause I am on my local machine, but this is going to a web server for production, how can the web server open the browser if there isn't any?

Comment: I don't know the details of your implementation, but since the user needs to authorize your application to interact with Google APIs with specific permissions, it still needs to happen from the browser.
Once the user authorizes the application, you configure a callback URL where you need to handle properly the code exchange (returned from Google) for an access token (that happens in your server) - you can read more about this here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server